# Trouble with gradient descent method for function fitting

Tags: machine-learning

I was trying to use the method of gradient descent to match the graph g(x) = 1 for x<0 and g(x) = 2x+1 for x>0 using the hypothesis class csigmoid(ax+b)+d, where a,b,c,d are parameters. The loss function I picked was squared loss error. However, the result I got from the following code is apparently not correct.

```
import math

cur_a = 1
cur_b = 3
cur_c = 3
cur_d = 3
rate = 0.0000000000001

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

data = [[-1, 1.0], [-0.75, 1.0], [-0.5, 1.0], [-0.25, 1], [0, 1], [0.25, 1.5], [0.5, 2], [0.75, 2.5], [1, 3], [1.25, 3.5], [1.5, 4]]

def gradienta():
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        ele = data[i]
        result += 2 * (cur_c * sigmoid(cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b) + cur_d - ele[1]) * cur_c * sigmoid(
            cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b) * (1 - sigmoid(cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b)) * ele[0]
    return result/len(data)


def gradientb():
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        ele = data[i]
        result += 2 * (cur_c * sigmoid(cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b) + cur_d - ele[1]) * cur_c * sigmoid(
            cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b) * (1 - sigmoid(cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b))
    return result/len(data)


def gradientc():
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        ele = data[i]
        result += 2 * (cur_c * sigmoid(cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b) + cur_d - ele[1]) * sigmoid(
           cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b)
    return result/len(data)


def gradientd():
    result = 0;
    for i in range(len(data)):
        ele = data[i]
        result += 2 * cur_c * sigmoid(cur_a * ele[0] + cur_b) + cur_d - ele[1]
    return result/len(data)

iters = 0
max_iters = 10000
precision = 0.00001
step_size = 1

while step_size > precision and iters < max_iters:
    # save previous location
    prev_a = cur_a
    prev_b = cur_b
    prev_c = cur_c
    prev_d = cur_d

    # move to new location according to steepest descent
    cur_a = cur_a - rate * gradienta()
    cur_b = cur_a - rate * gradientb()
    cur_c = cur_a - rate * gradientc()
    cur_d = cur_a - rate * gradientd()

    # update step_size and iters
    step_size = ((prev_a - cur_a) ** 2 + (prev_b - cur_b) ** 2 + (prev_c - cur_c) ** 2 + (prev_d - cur_d) ** 2) ** 0.5
    iters += 1

print(cur_a)
print(cur_b)
print(cur_c)
print(cur_d)
```

While the value of d seems plausible, I expect the value of a, b, and c to be around 5 and 10. The output of the code, however, is

1.0000000000000535

1.0000000000000615

1.0000000000003113

1.0000000000001017

where each value corresponding to one parameter. This is not a good match.

Any suggestions on where went wrong?

Comment: Your learning rate is very small. You should print the value of the loss or cost function during training to see if it is really decreasing, and what final value it converges, to see if you need to adjust learning rate or number of iterations

Comment: Thanks! I have tried several rate and number of iterations and found that the loss function would always first decrease and then increase unboundedly. I have checked the partial derivatives and they seem correct. Does this mean that this problem is probably not suited for gradient descent?

Comment: No, this just points that you are not training the model correcttly, or that the gradients are computed incorrectly